# How can I get a specific value from a JSON string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript object named `page.cat.lastResponseText`.

This object has the following **string** value:

```
{
    "orderBy":"",
    "orderDesc":false,
    "rows":[
        {"catIndId":"3","indId":"1","catId":"2"},         
        {"catIndId":"4","indId":"4","catId":"2"}
    ],
    "totalResults":2,
    "totalPages":1,
    "pageSize":2,
    "currentPage":1
}
```

How I can convert this string into a JSON object? And how do I then get the values for object such as ***cat.rows*** or ***cat.totalResults***?

Comment: This probably took you much longer than just typing "javascript string to json" in google.

Comment: Your question seems quite confused. You say you have a "JavaScript object", but then you say it's a string. I guess what you mean to say is "a string representation of an object". And I doubt if you want to convert it into a "JSON object"; I suppose you mean to say a "JavaScript object". in any case, yes, the way you do it is to parse the JSON string.

Comment: The question addresses not only the problem how to parse a JSON (which, ok, is duplicated), but also how to get then a specific value (so an appropriate search in google leads to this question). For the provided in the question example after parsing (`var mJsonObj=JSON.parse(jsonString)`) you can get specific value as follows: `var mVal=mJsonObj.orderDesc` gives `false`, `mJsonObj.totalResults` gives `2` and `mJsonObj.rows[0].catIndId` gives `3`, `mJsonObj.rows[1].catIndId` gives `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse()`

http://caniuse.com/#feat=json